# Problema con array como condicional

Tags: java, netbeans, condiciones, array-bidimensional

estoy haciendo un trabajo para aprender a programar en java con netbeans y tengo un problema con este código. En el main estoy intentado guardar las dimensiones de un parking y luego ver con un bucle for que plazas están ocupadas o no, en caso de que no este ocupada guardara en el objeto parking de la clase plaza en esa posición del array true y si ya estaba ocupada saltara a la siguiente posicion del for. El problema creo que viene dado de que al estar inicializado las variables nplaza y ncalle como 0 el valor que yo les de en el case 1 no se guardaran para el case 2 y me gustaria saber como evitar esto.

Mando dos codigos, uno es el codigo que usare en el main y el otro es el codigo de la clase plaza que tendra como atributos ocupada el cual es el mas importante con esta parte del trabajo y el resto ahora mismo no son relevantes.
La zona en la que da error esta marcada con un comentario a la derecha.

codigo del main:

```
public class prueba {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declaracion de variables
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nplaza = 0;     //numero de plazas total
        int ncalle = 0;     //numero de calles total
        int pplaza;         //posicion de la plaza
        int pcalle;         //posicion de la calle
        int selector;
        plaza[][] parking = new plaza[nplaza][ncalle];

        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        System.out.println("* 1.- Configurar parking");
        System.out.println("* 2.- Asignar plaza");
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        
        selector = teclado.nextInt();
        switch (selector) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de plazas");
                nplaza = teclado.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de calles");
                ncalle = teclado.nextInt();
                break;
            case 2:
                for (pcalle = 1; pcalle < ncalle; pcalle++) {
                    for (pplaza = 1; pplaza < nplaza; pplaza++) {
                        if (parking[pcalle][pplaza].isOcupada() == false) { //problema aqui

                            System.out.println("Se ha ocupado la plaza " + pplaza + " y la calle " + pcalle);
                            parking[pcalle][pplaza].setOcupada(true);

                        }

                    }
                }
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Codigo de la clase plaza

```
public class plaza {

    public boolean ocupada;
    public String matricula;
    public String horaInicioOcupacion;
    public char tipo;

    public plaza(boolean ocupada, String matricula, String horaInicioOcupacion, char tipo) {
        this.ocupada = ocupada;
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.horaInicioOcupacion = horaInicioOcupacion;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public boolean isOcupada() {
        return ocupada;
    }

    public void setOcupada(boolean ocupada) {
        this.ocupada = ocupada;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getHoraInicioOcupacion() {
        return horaInicioOcupacion;
    }

    public void setHoraInicioOcupacion(String horaInicioOcupacion) {
        this.horaInicioOcupacion = horaInicioOcupacion;
    }

    public char getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(char tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
```

Comment: Lo he mirado así por encima y con el móvil, pero cuando instancias parking lo estás haciendo [0][0], no es así?

Comment: Puede ser pero me gustaría que se quedara con los valores que le doy en el case 1 pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: por cierto que me falto mencionarlo ahora ncalle se inicia con 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad no entiendo muy bien el orden en que quieres ejecutar tu programa, en todo caso el problema principal es que nunca guardaste "Plazas" en la matriz asi que daba null.
Recuerda añadir el constructor vacio en la clase Plaza.
Por ultimo, las clases en java siempre comienzan con mayuscula.

```
public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
         Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            int nplaza = 0;     //numero de plazas total
            int ncalle = 0;     //numero de calles total
            int pplaza;         //posicion de la plaza
            int pcalle;         //posicion de la calle
            int selector;
            Plaza[][] parking = new Plaza[nplaza][ncalle];
            
            boolean salir=false;
            while (!salir) {
                
            
            System.out.println("*******************************************");
            System.out.println("* 1.- Configurar parking");
            System.out.println("* 2.- Asignar plaza");
            System.out.println("* 3.-Salir del programa");
            System.out.println("*******************************************");
            
            selector = teclado.nextInt();
            switch (selector) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de plazas");
                    nplaza = teclado.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de calles");
                    ncalle = teclado.nextInt();
                    parking= new Plaza[nplaza][ncalle];
                    for (int i = 0; i < parking.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < parking[i].length; j++) {
                            parking[i][j]= new Plaza();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                  
                case 2:
                    
                    for (pcalle = 1; pcalle < ncalle; pcalle++) {
                        for (pplaza = 1; pplaza < nplaza; pplaza++) {
                            if (parking[pcalle][pplaza].isOcupada() == false) { 

                                System.out.println("Se ha ocupado la plaza " + pplaza + " y la calle " + pcalle);
                                parking[pcalle][pplaza].setOcupada(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case 3:
                    salir=true;
            }
        }
    
    }
    
        
    }
```

---

Como puedes ver existe un while que va a ejecutar toda ese código mientras el usuario no digite un 3 y se cambie a true, ahora cuando el usuario ingrese la cantidad plazas y calles también se guardan objetos plaza en la matriz que era el error principal.

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad me soluciono el problema TuT